# Use element by css to check if element exists in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

In a protractor end to end test, I want to check if an element exist using element(by.css(...)), my code:

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.elementClass'));
expect(myElement).toBeUndefined;
```

This test fails, it says:

```
    Expected { locator_ : { using : 'css selector', value : 'div[ng-switch-
    when="resultNav"]' }, parentElementFinder_ : null, opt_actionResult_ :
    undefined, opt_index_ : undefined, click : Function, sendKeys : Function, 
getTagName : Function, getCssValue : Function, getAttribute : Function, getText
 : Function, getSize : Function, getLocation : Function, isEnabled : Function, 
isSelected : Function, submit : Function, clear : Function, isDisplayed : 
Function, getOuterHtml : Function, getInnerHtml : Function, toWireValue : 
Function } to be undefined.
```

After that I tried to use a promise:

```
element(by.css('.elementClass')).then( functtion(data) {
    expect(data.getText()).toBeUndefined();
});
```

This results in an error:

> Error: No element found using locator By.CssSelector(...)

Yes, I know that no element will be found, but how can I create a working test using element(`by.css(...)`)?

Does anyone know how to achieve this? or is `element(by.css())` not the method to use here?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can test whether the `element` is present with `isPresent`.  [Here are the protractor docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) for the `isPresent` function.

So, your code would be something like:

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.elementClass'));
expect(myElement.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: Thanks this did it! (see my comment at JB also)

Answer (score 28):

You need to test if the element is not present:

```
expect(element(by.css('.elementClass')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was sure I tried something like this, I feel stupid... Do you have any idea why the 'isPresent' method is not mentioned in the object in my failure message?

Comment: Because isPresent is added by protractor as a **prototype**. The ones you see in the error message are inherited from webdriver **as a property** of element. console.log and throws will not show prototypes by default

Comment: Your code appears to be checking that it is NOT present. Can you explain please?

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Truthy and falsie refer to values that are evaluated to true and false after being coerced to a boolean unless you want your function to return different types of values.

```
var myElement = element(by.css('.elementClass'));
myElement.isPresent().then(function (elm)
{
    if (elm)
    {
        console.log("... Element was found")
        expect(myElement.getText()).toBeUndefined();
    } else {
        console.log("... Element was not found")
    }
});
```

Comment: John, any chance to explain your answer please and why this is a better solution than the accepted answer with nearly 100 upvotes?

Comment: truthy and falsy refer to values that are evaluated to true and false after being coerced to a boolean.  Unless you want your function to return different types of values.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

same thing, but different syntax

```
let elem = $('.elementClass');
let elemIsPresent = await elem.isPresent();
expect(elemIsPresent).toBe(false);
```